# Norm Product expression

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces

Prove the product expression $$\left \| AB \right \|_{U\rightarrow W} \leq \left \| A \right \|_{V\rightarrow W}\left \| B \right \|_{U\rightarrow V}$$

Hint: consider $(AB)u = A(Bu)$ and apply $\left \| Av \right \|_{W}\leq \left \| A \right \|\left \| v \right \|_{V}$ twice

Unfortunately, I'm having a problem figuring out how to apply the hint because my knowledge of norms is very poor. I am hoping for a very comprehensions explanation so that I may learn how to handle norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is very simple
>   $$\|ABv\|_{W}\le \|A\|_{V\rightarrow W}\|Bv\|_{V}\le \|A\|_{V\rightarrow W}\|B\|_{U\rightarrow V}\|v\|_{V}$$
>   for all $v$, then immediately we get, 
>   $$\|AB\|_{U\rightarrow W}\le  \|A\|_{V\rightarrow W}\|B\|_{U\rightarrow V}.$$